# Catch HTTP-Posts from Android App

Tags: android, security, http

Is it possible for users of my Android Application to view the URLs/Post-Data of HTTP-Post Requests from this App? So they can manipulate it and also view it with their browser on a Desktop Computer?

Comment: Android aside, note that if you aren't using HTTPS, -everyone- can see the content of your traffic (for our purposes, everyone is any person sharing a network with the device or who is anywhere between the device and your server).

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library to do this by using the `beforeSend` callback, and set it as a global ajax setting:

```
$.ajaxSetup(new AjaxOptions().beforeSend(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        AjaxOptions options = (AjaxOptions) params[0];
        if (options.type().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
            //here, show the data stored in the AjaxOptions object, such as the URL, data type, headers, etc.
        }
    }
}));
```

Calling this method in your `onStart` method will set it so that all HTTP POST requests made using *Ajax* that are set as global (default) will trigger the given function before sending the request. Inside the `Function`, you can view and manipulate the `AjaxOptions` Object.

Comment: But I don't want anyone to be able to view/manipulate my requests. Does your anyswer mean that normally POST Requests aren't triggered?

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister, you can prevent your own post requests from being viewed or manipulated by either __a.__ not using *droidQuery*, or __b.__, setting the `AjaxOptions` *global* setting to false. As for your second question - only post requests that are sent using droidQuery's Ajax functions AND are set to global (default) will trigger this Function.